# How to bind Factory into current request scope?

Tags: jersey-2.0, hk2

How do I dynamically bind a new [Factory](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0-b05/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Factory.html) into the current request scope? I want the binding to get removed automatically at the end of the current HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The provide method of the Factory can be annotated with @RequestScope and then the thing provided by the factory will be in the RequestScope (and hence the factory provide method should get called every time the RequestScope changes).

Is this what you are asking?

It also depends on how you are binding it.  Are you using one of the automatic analyzers of the class, or are you using a bind API?

Even the Factory *itself* (not the provide method) can be in the RequestScope, in which case a new instance of the Factory implementation will get created whenever the RequestScope changes

Comment: How can I use the bind API to bind both the factory and the instance it returns to RequestScope, if both are bound by instance instead of by class? Meaning, the factory/value instances might outlive RequestScope, but I want their binding to get removed automatically once the scope ends.

Comment: The definition of a scope/context ending is up to the implementation of the scope/context.  RequestScope is probably coming from Jersey, not hk2.  So I guess this is a Jersey question!